# Can this code cause a managed heap corruption?

Tags: c#, debugging, garbage-collection, crash

I'm trying to debug a crash that happens in our application during garbage collection and looking at the code I found two related pieces of code that, if not the cause of the problem, are at least suspicious to me:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 96, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, Pack=1)]
public class MilbusData
{
  public System.Int64 TimeStamp;
  public System.Int16 Lane;
  public System.Int16 TerminalAddress;
  public System.Int16 TerminalSubAddress;
  public System.Int16 Direction;   
  public System.Int64 ErrorCounter;   
  public System.Int64 MessageCounter;   
  public System.Int16 RTErrorState;     
  [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
  public System.UInt16[] Data;
}
```

Note that from my understanding the struct is actually at least 98 bytes in size but is declared as 96 bytes long (the code compiles though).

The second suspicious piece of code is related to the above struct:

```
MilbusData^ ret = nullptr;
if (m_Stream->Read(m_RawData, 0, sizeof(TMilbusData)) == sizeof(TMilbusData))
{
  GCHandle pinnedRawData = GCHandle::Alloc(m_RawData, GCHandleType::Pinned);

  ret = (MilbusData^)Marshal::PtrToStructure(pinnedRawData.AddrOfPinnedObject(), 
                                             MilbusData::typeid);

   pinnedRawData.Free();
}
```

where m_RawData is a simple unsigned byte array and TMilbusData is the C++ (native) code analogous of the above struct, defined as

```
typedef struct
{
  __int64 TimeStamp;
  short Lane;
  short TerminalAddress;
  short TerminalSubAddress;
  short Direction;
  __int64 ErrorCounter;
  __int64 MessageCounter;
  short RTErrorState;
  unsigned char Data[64];
} TMilbusData;
```

What I'm not sure about in this second case is if the conversion from the native struct to a managed *reference type* is safe (note that MilbusData is not declared as a value type).

As I said the crashes that we are experiencing occur normaly during garbage collection but are sometimes extremely difficult to reproduce. I gave more details about the crash itself in another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7580577/causes-for-crash-during-garbage-collection)  but what I want to ask here is:

- Is the code above safe?
- And if not can it be the cause for a managed heap corruption and explain therefore the crashes that we are experiencing?

**EDIT**: I should probably have asked if it is *absolutely positive* that the issues that I found in the code (as the mismatching structure sizes between native and managed code) can be the cause for a crash in the GC. Reason for asking is that i) The C# compiler doesn't complain about the wrong structure size and ii) The problem is very difficult to reproduce. I'm right now having a hard time in making it crash in the "old" version (where the size of the struct is wrong) and I wanted to avoid following a possible dead-end since each testing can take many days..

Comment: Just a quick scan of the code shows you are redefining the `ret` value inside the if statement of your second block of code. That could lead to confusion if nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, it was a mistake while editing the code to post it here, it's fixed now.

Comment: You are not creating enough space in your managed code. Your array also is different sizes. Have you verified the structure works in its current size, because based on what you posted, its not even to big enough to hold everything.  What Military Standard is this, looks almost like MIL-STD-1553.  How is you C# code aware of your C++ code, normally I have to create a wrapper class, if I am dealing with something like this

Comment: Wondering why in the C# version of the struct, the array is declared as 32 `UInt16` objects as opposed to 64 `Byte` objects that the C++ structure has. If it is a direct block of memory they should occupy the same space, but I can see that leading to confusion and errors downstream.

Comment: @Ramhound: yes, I see that the structures are different in size but what I'm asking is if this alone would explain the crashes that we're experiencing (the code compiles with the wrong and right - 98 bytes - size);

Comment: @pstrjds - The two structures do not appear to be the same size.  The two data collections at second glance does appear to be the same size, only because the int16 would hole two characters be element.

Comment: @pstrjds: array is declared as 32x2 bytes in C# only as a matter of convenience since each value is actualy 16 bit.. I also think that this should not be a problem but I agree with you, the C++ version of the array should then also have been declared as 32x2 instead of 64x1 values to avoid confusion.

Comment: @floyd73 - The code compiles because there is nothing wrong witht the code syntax wise.  You need to make the two structures the correct size.  When dealing with PtrToStructure you are responsible to make sure you create a certain size and also destroy the same size.  Be sure you take into account the number of elements with data, when requesting the memory to do so, otherwise you won't have neough

Comment: @floyd73 - Sure, I realize they should occupy the same space, but if you are trying to index the data and you are not careful, you can run off the end of the buffer. Not knowing the reasoning behind the code I can't comment on whether you should do it or not, I was just pointing out an area that could cause confusion. As far as the issue of the `Size`, according to the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute.size.aspx), this must be equal or greater than the size needed for the struct. Does it still crash when it is set to 98?

Comment: @Ramhoud - but shouldn't the compiler see that 96 bytes are not sufficient to store the struct and see this as an error? In any case, could this alone explain the crashes during garbage collection?

Comment: @pstrjds - about the different sizes I saw that but my question is if this alone can cause a heap corruption (I'm currently testing this but as I mentioned this problem is sometimes very difficult to reproduce)

Comment: @pstrjds: I'm testing if it doesn't crash with 98 as the size but then again I'm having a hard time making it crash again with the old size in our test PC (this might take days) and to not follow a possible dead end I wanted therefore to ask if it is absolutely positive that this could explain why the GC is crashing..

Comment: @floyd to help you catch the heap corruption faster you should use [gflags](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdav_101/archive/2010/06/22/detecting-heap-corruption-using-gflags-and-dumps.aspx). It will make the code crash as soon as heap corruption occurs.

Comment: @pstrjds: AFAIK gflags and the heap corruption check works only with unmanaged code (our main application is written in C#).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but shouldn't the compiler see that 96 bytes are not sufficient to
>   store the struct and see this as an error? In any case, could this
>   alone explain the crashes during garbage collection?

You might only want to store a certain amount of the data, say the first 16 bits, of the 32  bits of an integer.

By saying the size of the structure is limited to 96 bytes, if you attempt to place more then 96 bytes into the structure, you will attempt to go outside of the memory you allocated based on the size of the structure.

This means you will 1) Only hold 96 bytes in the structure 2) When you attempt to place more then the allocated memory run into memory mangement problems.

As I have already said, there is nothing wrong with your code, it will compile.  its simply not correct in this instance, and the structure is not declared correctly, so you should either not declare the size or declare the correct size.

> EDIT: I should probably have asked if it is absolutely positive that
>   the issues that I found in the code (as the mismatching structure
>   sizes between native and managed code) can be the cause for a crash in
>   the GC. Reason for asking is that i) The C# compiler doesn't complain
>   about the wrong structure size and ii) The problem is very difficult
>   to reproduce. I'm right now having a hard time in making it crash in
>   the "old" version (where the size of the struct is wrong) and I wanted
>   to avoid following a possible dead-end since each testing can take
>   many days..

All I can promise you is the structure size is not correct at 96 bytes, I cannot tell you if the problem you have with crash connected to the garbage collector, is connect to this structure.  If this structure is wrong what other structures are wrong?

I would fix the size, and make sure Data is the correct type, to match the data you will recieve from your device.

Comment: thanks Ramhound, as I mentioned in our discussion in the comments I'm currently testing if the application crashes with the structure declared with the correct size but this can take many days. I will post my results here after testing and leave the question open until then.

Comment: @floyd73 - You should verify that **m_RawData** is the correct size before you continue to test.  I do not believe that sizeof will be able to determine the size of your array if its empty.

Comment: I just made the old application crash again and will now test the fixed code and see if it doesn't crash in the next 24 hours or so, thanks for your help! (and about the m_RawData it is allocated only once so it's size is constant, what I'm checking in the if clause is how many bytes where read from the stream)

Comment: So after almost a day of testing without crashing I'm pretty sure that the problem was indeed the 2 bytes difference between the size of the structs so I'm accepting this answer, thank you again for the support.

Comment: @floyd73 - The reason I wanted you to verify that **m_RawData** was the correct number of bytes was because of the crash. In order to understand the crash, think about the allocation as a box in memory, trying to place stuff outside of the box is an illegal operation. So if the volume of the box ( i.e. **m_RawData** ) you will get the size of the box wrong, this isn't always the case, because you don't always stuff the box to its limit.